# Is it possible to add more elements to a collection with bounded generic type

Tags: generics, java-8

I tried to declare a set in the following way with bounded generic type:

`Set<? extends Number> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();`

Then I tried `numbers.add(new Integer(1));`, it can not compile. So I would like to know is it possible to add any kind of element to the set I defined? Or doesn't that way of declaration make any sense?

Comment: You told the compiler that `numbers` might be a `Set<Integer>` or `Set<Double>` or `Set<BigDecimal>` etc. What can you safely add to a set parametrized by *any* subtype of `Number`?  Only `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People often mix up polymorphism and covariance.

This is polymorphic set:

```
Set<Number> numbers;
```

you can add `Integer`, `Double` or any other value to `numbers` that extends `Number`. And you can iterate over its elements and will be able to use any method of class Number on its items. But you can *only* assign another `Set<Number>` to this variable. Not `Set<Integer>` or `Set<Double>` or `Set<Object>`. Because this declaration is ***invariant***.

This is **covariant** set:

```
Set<? extends Number> numbers;
```

Such variable can hold `Set<Number>`, `Set<Integer>`, `Set<Double>` etc. Assuming you want to sum up all numbers in such a collection as doubles, you can write

```
double sum(Set<? extends Number> numbers) { 
   ... iterate and sum up using item.doubleValue() ...
}
```

only once! For all kinds of collections that satisfy `? extends Number`. Otherwise you would need to write one method for `Set<Double>`, a separate one for `Set<Integer>` etc.

Think of it as another dimension in the type system. `Set<Number>`allows you to have polymorphic *elements*, `Set<? extends Number>` allows you to have polymorphic *collections* (of polymorphic elements). I.e. polymorphism squared.

Now, there are logical limitations to what you can *do* with such collections. This is correct statement:

```
Set<? extends Number> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

but after this line compiler "forgets" that in reality there were integers. It doesn't know. It assumes there might be `new HashSet<AtomicDouble>()` or what not. Surely you cannot add integer to a set of atomic doubles. In fact, nothing meaningful can be added safely to this set that will work in any situation, regardless of set of what it is. This variable can even hold a set of something that wasn't invented yet in this universe. So, covariant collections are only good for reading.

What is good for putting stuff in? **Contravariant** collections.

```
   Set<? super Number> numbers1 = new HashSet<Number>(); //ok
   Set<? super Number> numbers2 = new HashSet<Object>(); //also ok
```

Now we are talking. The declaration `<? super Number>` tells us no future code can *limit* the contents of this set to anything more specific than Number, but it is ok to be more generic. So, it is safe to add *any* kind of number to either `numbers1` or `numbers2`. Because even if in reality the content is a set of objects, a boxed number is fine, it is still an object. So, contravariant collection is great for putting stuff in, for writing. But you will be very limited in your options when reading. Because, well, you have to assume that initially there might have been a set of objects assigned to it that had nothing to do with numbers. It was just guaranteed that you can safely add any kind of number. If you need to do both, reading and writing, you are back to square one with invariant collections.

As a side note, this is not a Java limitation, it follows from the algebraic rules applied to polymorphic type system. I.e. it is pure logic and cannot be "fixed" by changing the language or improving Java.

Comment: `you can only assign another Set<Number>...` well you can obviously assign it to `Set<?>`

Comment: True, you can assign this variable to `Set<?>` (which, in most cases is synonymous to `Set<? extends Object>`). But it does not contradict my statement: only another `Set<Number>` can be assigned to a variable declared as `Set<Number>`. It can be HashSet or TreeSet or what not, but it has to be invariant set of `Number` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Upper Bound collections are kind of immutable, in the way you can't add elements to them, but you can of course remove from them.
Explanation is easy: Java doesn’t know what type `List<? extends Number>` is. Could be `List<AtomicInteger` or a `List<Byte>` or any other subclass of *Number*.
This line:

```
numbers.add(new Integer(1));
```

does not compile because *numbers* could be `List<Double>`and we can’t add an *Integer* to a list of *Double*.

So you may think that declaring a list with Upper Bound `<? extends T>`
it's pointless, but it's not.
Such a declaration makes sense in the contest of a method signature. For instances I can declare a method like this:

```
public void printInteger(List<? extends Number> list){
    list.forEach(n-> System.out.println(n.intValue()));
}
```

This method can be invoked with any List whose type extends *Integer*, for instances I can use:

```
printInteger(new ArrayList<Integer>());
printInteger(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of declaration doesn't make sense, because the variable allows any subtype of `Number` while the value allows only integers in the set. You should declare and define `numbers` as

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

if your set can only include integers, or

```
Set<Number> numbers = new HashSet<Number>();
```

if it allows other numeric type like `java.lang.Double`, too.